# Adaptative card button send via api graph doesn't work on PC but works on mobile

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We use api graph to send an adaptative card with messageBack button. The card appears on mobile and PC properly, when we click the button on mobile the message is send but doesn't do anything on PC.

Here is what we sent with api graph. (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{channel-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages)

```
{  
    "subject": null,  
    "body": {  
        "contentType": "html",  
        "content": "<attachment id=\"74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5\"></attachment>"  
    },  
    "attachments": [  
        {  
            "id": "74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5",  
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",  
            "contentUrl": null,  
            "content": "{\r\n  \"title\": \"This is an example of posting a card\",\r\n  \"subtitle\": \"<h3>This is the subtitle</h3>\",\r\n  \"text\": \"Here is some body text. <br>\\r\\nAnd a <a href=\\\"http://microsoft.com/\\\">hyperlink</a>. <br>\\r\\nAnd below that is some buttons:\",\r\n  \"buttons\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"type\": \"messageBack\",\r\n      \"title\": \"Login to FakeBot\",\r\n      \"text\": \"login\",\r\n      \"displayText\": \"login\",\r\n      \"value\": \"login\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}",  
            "name": null,  
            "thumbnailUrl": null  
        }  
    ]  
}
```

[adaptative card result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wvHE.png)

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same. We will inform in this thread once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

Comment: We got confirmation from engineering team that, this is by design. 'imBack' or 'messageBack' invoke won't work through Graph. Only 'openUrl' will.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually not sending an 'Adaptive' Card, you're sending a 'Thumbnail' card (`application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail`). See more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference) and try it with an actual Adaptive Card, you might have better results.

To find out more about Adaptive Cards specifically, as well as try out the designer and some sample cards, see https://adaptivecards.io/

Comment: Tried to repro this and using `"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"` also it is behaving in the same way. In Android devices its working, but in Teams desktop/web client it doesn't.

Comment: It's not just the content type - the payload doesn't match an Adaptive Card syntex. Both need to change.

Comment: We got confirmation from engineering team that, this is by design. 'imBack' or 'messageBack' invoke won't work through Graph. Only 'openUrl' will.